# Why does EF6 insert a row in parent table when inserting row in child table?

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have 2 DB tables which are connected to each other using foreign key and I am creating this table using entity framework 6 and Sqlite using below models.

```
public class IntegraPortal : BaseEntity
{
        
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string DatabaseIp{ get; set; }
        
    public string DatabaseName{ get; set; }
        
    public string DatabaseLogin{ get; set; }
        
    public string DatabasePassword{ get; set; }

    #region Navigation
        
    public virtual List<Plc> Plcs{ get; set; }

    #endregion
}

public class Plc :  BaseEntity
{   

        public string Name{ get; set; }
        
        public string Ip{ get; set; }
        
        public int Slot{ get; set; }

        public int Mode{ get; set; }

        public string Craft{ get; set; }

        public string Area{ get; set; }

        public int IntegraPortalId { get; set; }

        #region Navigation
        
        public virtual IntegraPortal IntegraPortal { get; set; }

        #endregion
 }
```

Model Configuration:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<IntegraPortal>();

modelBuilder.Entity<Plc>()
            .HasRequired(x => x.IntegraPortal)
            .WithMany(s => s.Plcs)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.IntegraPortalId);
```

Code Generated using EF6:

```
public override void Up()
        {
            CreateTable(
                "dbo.IntegraPortals",
                c => new
                    {
                        Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                        Name = c.String(maxLength: 2147483647),
                        DatabaseIp = c.String(maxLength: 2147483647),
                        DatabaseName = c.String(maxLength: 2147483647),
                        DatabaseLogin = c.String(maxLength: 2147483647),
                        DatabasePassword = c.String(maxLength: 2147483647),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);
            
            CreateTable(
                "dbo.Plcs",
                c => new
                    {
                        Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                        Name = c.String(maxLength: 2147483647),
                        Ip = c.String(maxLength: 2147483647),
                        Slot = c.Int(nullable: false),
                        Mode = c.Int(nullable: false),
                        Craft = c.String(maxLength: 2147483647),
                        Area = c.String(maxLength: 2147483647),
                        IntegraPortalId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
                .ForeignKey("dbo.IntegraPortals", t => t.IntegraPortalId, cascadeDelete: true)
                .Index(t => t.IntegraPortalId, name: "IX_Plc_IntegraPortalId");

CreateTable(
                "dbo.History_82c009b41631-48579635f1ff64eb62d9",
                c => new
                    {
                        Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                        Hash = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 2147483647),
                        Context = c.String(maxLength: 2147483647),
                        CreateDate = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);
            
        }
```

But now if I try to insert a PLC(Child) object with an existing IntegraPortal(Parent) object. It creates a new parent object (duplicates the existing one) with new id and referencing that new id in the child table.

I don't want to create a new row in parent table. I just want to insert a new row in child table referencing the existing row in parent table.

this is how I am inserting new row to child table with existing parent object.
here config is an object of existing row in Parent table.

```
var plc = new Plc();
plc.Name = reader[1].ToString();
plc.Ip = reader[2].ToString();
plc.Slot = Convert.ToInt32(reader[3]);
plc.Mode = Convert.ToInt32(reader[4]);
plc.Craft = reader[7].ToString();
plc.Area = reader[6].ToString();
plc.IntegraPortalId = config.Id;
plc.IntegraPortal = config;

dataAccess.AddPlc(plc);
```

would like to know if I am doing anything wrong in model configuration or table creation.
Any help is appreciated.
TIA.

Comment: You should have a 3 table, to be the relation of the Plc with the IntegraPortal

Comment: @Camadas Hi, Can you please explain why I need 3 table and how to create a 3rd table(with what column properties)?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by removing `plc.IntegraPortal = config;` from the code.

I should not give the parent row object (row in parent table) in the child. I should only give the id of the parent row as foreign key for child table.

Modified code:

```
var plc = new Plc();
plc.Name = reader[1].ToString();
plc.Ip = reader[2].ToString();
plc.Slot = Convert.ToInt32(reader[3]);
plc.Mode = Convert.ToInt32(reader[4]);
plc.Craft = reader[7].ToString();
plc.Area = reader[6].ToString();
plc.IntegraPortalId = config.Id; //foreign key -- parent table row id

dataAccess.AddPlc(plc);
```

With this no duplicate row is added in the parent table.